# Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy with SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, sprite-kit, hierarchy

When I push the twitter image in the game, I want to show share image(SLComposeViewController's modal display).

But, when I push the twitter button, the display doesn't show and the log says like the title.
Then, I searched similar issues but I am not sure what should I do...
[ViewDidLoad] and [ViewDidAppear] is important thing, I know.
Below is my code.

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewGameScene.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import "GameOverScene.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  GameOverScene *gameOver;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

//Loads the view onto our main class
- (void)loadView
{
self.view  = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
}

//Executes when view finishes loading
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
 { 
 //extracted important code.
 [super viewDidLoad];
 gameOver = [[GameOverScene alloc]init];
 gameOver.delegate = self;
 }

-(void)showShareScreen
{
NSLog(@"showShareScreen");
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController                                                
    poseViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"TestTweet from the Game !!"];
     NSLog(@"self = %@",self);
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
else {
    NSLog(@"not sls type twitter");
}
}
@end
```

MainScene.m

```
#import "MainScene.h"
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "Obstacle.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

static GameOverScene *gameOver;
-(void)die{

    //Create our game over scene with the current scene's dimensions
    GameOverScene *gameOver = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    gameOver.delegate = vc;
    NSLog(@"vc = %@",vc);

    [gameOver didMoveToView:self.view];

    //Present the game over scene with the fade in transition
    [self.scene.view presentScene:gameOver transition:transition];

}];
}
```

GameOverScene.m

```
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import "NewGameScene.h"
#import "MainScene.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>


//Screen is touched
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

//Same as in NewGameScene menu
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

//Is the retry button touched?
if([node.name isEqualToString:@"twitterbutton"]){
    NSLog(@"self.delegate = %@",self.delegate);
    [self.delegate showShareScreen];
    if (nil == self.delegate) NSLog(@"delegate is nil"); 
}  
}
@end
```

Comment: The error is saying that the presenting viewcontroller (`ViewController`) is not currently visible, and therefore cannot present another view controller. The modal needs to be presented from a visible view controller.

Comment: [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350938/attempt-to-present-on-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Comment: I added  tweetSheet.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
tweetSheet.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        
But it isn't solved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is described in the comment below.

```
GameOverScene *gameOver = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];

ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];//This is causing the problem.
//The delegate has to be the viewController which is presenting the scene

gameOver.delegate = vc;
NSLog(@"vc = %@",vc);

[gameOver didMoveToView:self.view]; //Why are you calling this line??

//Present the game over scene with the fade in transition
[self.scene.view presentScene:gameOver transition:transition];
```

Instead of the line:

```
gameOver.delegate = vc;
```

Try using this line instead:

```
gameOver.delegate = self.view.window.rootViewController;
```

EDIT:

Using the line

```
gameOver.delegate = (ViewController*) self.view.window.rootViewController;
```

should remove the warning

Comment: Thank you so much !! I finally got it. I appreciate you. But, there is a coution "Assigning to 'id<sceneDelegate>'from incompatible type 'UIViewController' " in the line. May I ask do you know the reason why ?　And, may I ask how to add your reputation ?

Comment: If this answer suits you, just accept it by clicking on the tick-mark next to it. Also, a vote-up will help.

Comment: I'll check and study it and thank you so much to teach me everything  !!