# Error while presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to switch from one view controller to another and I am getting this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

The code I'm using is the following:

```
view2 *v2 = [[view2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:v2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt to present \* on \* whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350938/attempt-to-present-on-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) or [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy).

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points here.

You are creating a new view controller passing `nil` as a parameter of `initWithNibName:bundle` method.  If you pass `nil`, as per the doc, the `nibName` property is set to `nil`. Is this that you want? Where the code is running into? Into another view controller? Into the app delegate?

Classes should start with a capital letter. e.g `View2`, `ViewController2`. Variable or properties with camel case notation. e.g. `myProperty`, `myView`.

`view2` should renamed as `ViewController2` (or whatever you want) since it's a controller and not a view.

Finally, what's your goal? When you ask a problem you should describe the context you are running in. On the contrary you should receive downvotes.